# Disable angularJs routing, routeprovider already gone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, url-routing

I am building a laravel + AngularJS application where laravel handles the routing (because of security issues).
At first I experimented a bit with AngularJS routing so I used a routeprovider etc.
Now that I am trying to get rid of this, angularJS keeps adding #/partofthelink  to the end of my URL.
This is quite annoying and I want to get rid of it.

I have already read a lot about removing the routeprovider etc, this has all been done. I really don't get where it comes from.

I have been trying a lot for a few days now.

Any ideas what might cause this ?

Thanks!

UPDATE:
Problem solved.

Had $route service somewhere in use. Got rid of it, still no success.
Now it seems that Bootstrap-ui makes use of the $location service when using a dropdown.
So I also deleted it over there.
Now everything is working fine.

Thanks!

Comment: If Angular is adding something to the link (that is performing a redirect), there must be a `routerProvider` left somewhere. If possible, post your code here.

Comment: For others who found the "UPDATE" section of this question helpful, this comment in the related AngularJS bug will also be of interest:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4608#issuecomment-32713399

Answer (score 6, accepted):

do you use $location service? then you have to get rid of that too